# kube-proxy not bind the 0.0.0.0

Tags: kubernetes

```
[root@k8s-m3 ~]# curl -I 172.16.1.9:30394
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.15.9
Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2019 15:22:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Feb 2019 14:13:39 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5c754993-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

[root@k8s-m3 ~]# curl -I 172.16.1.240:30394 # timeout
[root@k8s-m3 ~]# grep bind /etc/kubernetes/kube-proxy.conf 
bindAddress: 0.0.0.0
```

the config's file had bind the 0.0.0.0, but the second ip cannot be accessed.

Comment: please elaborate, provide more info about configurations and definitions files, are you exposing services using Service? Ingress?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/75443

Comment: Please update the question with relevant information so it stands on its own. Having said that, the linked issue also doesn't have any information about your setup whatsoever. If you shared your scenario clearly it would be much easier for other to see the problem on their own and try to help.